# How to make my sprite bounce off the boundaries in pygame

Tags: python, vector, pygame

So basically I want to try to make the Sprite bounce off the boundaries of my pygame screen (1920, 1020) but it doesn't work along with the player movement. For me, either have the player movement or the bounce. The code below includes the player movement but not the bounce. But I want bottth... Any ideas? Thanks! Credits to Rabbid76 and Ann Zen.

Code:

```
import pygame
import os
import random
import math
import winsound
# winsound.PlaySound("explosion.wav", winsound.SND_ALIAS)

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d,%d" % (0, 30)
wn = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1020))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
icon = pygame.image.load('Icon.png')
pygame.image.load('Sprite0.png')
pygame.image.load('Sprite0.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
pygame.display.set_caption('DeMass.io')




class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        z = random.randint(1, 2)
        if z == 2:
            self.original_image = pygame.image.load('Sprite0.png')
        else:
            self.original_image = pygame.image.load('Sprite3.png')
        self.image = self.original_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(x, y))
        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2((0, -1))
        self.velocity = 5
        self.position = pygame.math.Vector2(x, y)


    def point_at(self, x, y):
        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(x, y) - self.rect.center
        if self.direction.length() > 0:
            self.direction = self.direction.normalize()
        angle = self.direction.angle_to((0, -1))
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original_image, angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

    def move(self, x, y):
        self.position -= self.direction * y * self.velocity
        self.position += pygame.math.Vector2(-self.direction.y, self.direction.x) * x * self.velocity
        self.rect.center = round(self.position.x), round(self.position.y)


    def reflect(self, NV):
        self.direction = self.direction.reflect(pygame.math.Vector2(NV))

    def update(self):
        self.position += self.direction * self.velocity
        self.rect.center = round(self.position.x), round(self.position.y)

    def hit(self, player):
        distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(self.xcor() - player.xcor(), 2) + math.pow(self.ycor() - player.ycor(), 2))
        if distance < 20:
            return True
        else:
            return False



player = Player(200, 200)



while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            player.point_at(*event.pos)




    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_w] or keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        player.move(0, -1)






    wn.fill((255, 255, 255))
    all_sprites.draw(wn)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "bounce"? The player doesn't move automatically. Do you want to restrict the player to the window?

Comment: Oh okay. I was hoping that the player, yes, would be restricted to the boundaries of the screen, but instead of just not being able to go off the screen, bounce off it. Player 1 hits the screen, oof, he bounces off it. Thanks!

Comment: I don't get it. How should the player bounce? What are the criteria to bounce? How far should he bounce?

Comment: I was hoping he'd  be able to bounce about 10-20 pixels. Bounce means reflecting on the wall. Thanks!

Comment: That's not an easy task, because is should not bounce at once. It should be an animation over a few frames, depending on the speed of the player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to restrict the player to a rectangular area, you must restrict the player's `position` and `rect` attributes. Add an additional argument `clamp_rect` to the method `move`. If the player's position exceeds the boundaries of the rectangle, move the player inside the rectangle:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def move(self, x, y, clamp_rect):
        self.position -= self.direction * y * self.velocity
        self.position += pygame.math.Vector2(-self.direction.y, self.direction.x) * x * self.velocity
        self.rect.center = round(self.position.x), round(self.position.y)

        if self.rect.left < clamp_rect.left:
            self.rect.left = clamp_rect.left
            self.position.x = self.rect.centerx
        if self.rect.right > clamp_rect.right:
            self.rect.right = clamp_rect.right
            self.position.x = self.rect.centerx
        if self.rect.top < clamp_rect.top:
            self.rect.top = clamp_rect.top
            self.position.y = self.rect.centery
        if self.rect.bottom > clamp_rect.bottom:
            self.rect.bottom = clamp_rect.bottom
            self.position.y = self.rect.centery
```

Pass the window rectangle (`wn.get_rect()`) to `move`:

```py
while True:
    # [...]

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_w] or keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        player.move(0, -1, wn.get_rect())

    # [...]
```

Comment: K, the bouncing effect is had. But this code surely works so the player cant get out of the frame! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

make a bounce animation. define your boundaries and when you hit a wall make the animation run. (for this example you have to predefine hit_wall and have an if statement to check if it is on your boundaries)
Example:

```
if hit_wall:
    animate(direction)
```

```
def animate(direction):
    if direction == (0, 1):
        /code to make it bounce the opposite direction
    elif direction == (0, -1):
        /code to make it bounce the opposite direction
    elif direction == (1, 0):
        /code to make it bounce the opposite direction
    elif direction == (-1, 0):
        /code to make it bounce the opposite direction
```

Comment: Lol I already go this part. Just wondering how to be able to incorporate it with my main code without any glitches... Thanks anyway!